# Android gradle remove log

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I've created an application in android in release mode.
I want to remove all the logs in my project when i'm publishing my app in release mode.
how can i do it without duplicating my code?
can i remove the log using Gradle ?

Comment: You can use ProGuard or Timber and set pant only for debug mode

Comment: Are you talking about logcat, or some other type of logging?

Comment: pay attention to loglevels. when setting debuggable to false in build.gradle, all log.d will be removed. log.e and others will remain. usually this is good.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of BuildConfig.DEBUG variable, which will be true for debug builds and false otherwise.

You could have a Constants file with a variable like

```
public static final LOG_ENABLED = BuildConfig.DEBUG;
```

then check the variable before you print a log.

```
if(Constants.LOG_ENABLED){
   // print Log
}
```

Comment: I dont want to see the Log  in my code in release mode.

Comment: Yeah, that's what the BuildConfig.DEBUG is for. It's value will be false for release builds. So, the Constants.LOG_ENABLED will be false.

Comment: i'll try to be more clear. when i create an apk and do some reverse enginering i can still see the log data . i dont want others to see what i wrote on Log.

Comment: it should be stripped out by minifyEnabled (aka proguard) because it is an unrechable statement when LOG_ENABLED returns false in every case.

Comment: @SatelliteSD's comment must clear your doubt. Here is bit more detailed explanation. In your gradle file , add something like this
    android {
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled true
                shrinkResources true
            }
        }
    }

minifyEnabled will strip out the code which is unreachable, as in our case LOG_ENABLED is always false for a release build.